# Nativescript - accessing 'Binding Context' with a Button Reference

Tags: javascript, button, event-handling, nativescript

I'm new to native-script. I'm using "thenativescriptbook" by the Brosteins to learn the basics.

I'm trying to understand the reference/argument passed by a `<Button tap=EventHandler>` versus the `<Page Loaded=EventHandler>`. I feel like the Button Event Handler should only pass a reference to `<button></button>` contents...and not the `<page></page>` contents (within which it is contained)? Thus the bindingContext shouldn't access the items in `<page></page>`, but those in `<button></button>`? (obviously I know this isn't true; also I know the variable name doesn't matter (i.e. page))

If you look at the code below, my understanding is that the reference passed by the "onLoaded" "args.object" is the `<page>` reference (which will then in turn, monitor for databound items inside `<page></page>`). Wheres the "onTap" "args.object" is only referencing the `<button></button>` contents? (which doesn't include the items which are databound)?

How does the onTap event handler access the `<page></page>` databound context when it seems to only point at the `<button></button>`?

```
    scrapbook-page.xml

        <Page loaded="onLoaded">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label text="Title: " />
                <TextField class="header" text="{{title}}" />
                <Label text="Age: " />
                <DatePicker date="{{ date }}" />
                <Label text="Gender: " />
                <ListPicker items="{{ genders }}" selectedIndex="{{ gender }}" /> 
                <Button tap="onTap" text="Done" />
           </StackLayout>
        </Page>
```

```
    scrapbook-page.js

        var observable = require("data/observable");

        exports.onLoaded = function (args) {
            var page = args.object; // this is referencing the <page> object
            var scrapbook = new observable.fromObject({ 
                genders: ["Female", "Male", "Other"],
                gender: null, //#A
                date: null,    //#A
                title: null //#A
            });                                         

            page.bindingContext = scrapbook;
        };

        exports.onTap = function (args) {
            var page = args.object; // this is referencing the <button> object? not <page>
            var scrapbook = page.bindingContext;

            console.log("You have made " + scrapbook.title);
            console.log("Age: " + scrapbook.date.toLocaleDateString());
            console.log("Gender selected:" + scrapbook.genders[scrapbook.gender]);
        }
```

Appreciate any help clearing up what seems to be a fundamental.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

args.object is pointing to page object only throughout the app. and button is its child. and important to note args.object is singleton, even if you try to create more args.object it refers to previously created object address only. so in onloaded event of page you have created args.object then on button click you are accessing that. hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Every object will have reference to the page it's residing, so `args.object.page` should do the trick for you. Besides in your example the `bindingContext` for the Button and Page should be same, the `bindingContext` may be different for each item only within components like Repeater / ListView.

Go through [API reference](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_core_view_.view#page) for such information.